# how to set the scala compiler when the scala file has chinese char for comments

Tags: scala

i comment the code line of the Rational.scala file in chinese like this:

```
var a = new Rational(-4,6)
var b = new Rational(3,-9)
var c = a + a * b //满足运算符的优先级别
```

when i run the command:

> scala Rational.scala

it throws a exception. whereas i leave the comment off or comment in English,it's ok!

Somewhat do i config?

very thanks

fyi: this is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main (args = , classpath = d:\DOCUME~1\LUJUNM~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\scalascript3969467400078546162.tmp;C:\Program%20Files\
Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Prog
ram%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\ext\
dnsns.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Progra
m%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\SCALA-~1.FIN\bin\..\lib\jline.ja
r;C:\SCALA-~1.FIN\bin\..\lib\scala-compiler.jar;C:\SCALA-~1.FIN\bin\..\lib\scala-dbc.jar;C:\SCALA-~1.FIN\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\SCALA-~1.FIN\
bin\..\lib\scala-swing.jar;C:\SCALA-~1.FIN\bin\..\lib\scalap.jar;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;C:\Program%20Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\lib)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.scala$tools$nsc$ScriptRunner$$runCompiled(ScriptRunner.scala:171)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScriptRunner.scala:157)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.waitingForThreads(package.scala:26)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:130)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:201)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:58)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: Are those Chinese characters contained in the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane or Supplementary Characters?

Comment: that's the desc in wikipedia:'Basic Multilingual Plane
A map of the Basic Multilingual Plane. Each numbered box represents 256 code points.
The first plane, plane 0, the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), is where most characters have been assigned so far. The BMP contains characters for almost all modern languages, and a large number of special characters. A primary objective for the BMP is to support the unification of prior character sets as well as characters for writing. Most of the allocated code points in the BMP are used to encode **Chinese**, Japanese, and Korean (CJK) characters.'

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using Windows, and the default charset for Windows is not UTF-8.

Do this:

1. Make sure you know what's the charset in which the source file was written. Preferably, UTF-8.
2. Use the parameter `-encoding` to specify the charset to be used. For example, `scalac -enconding utf8 Rational.scala`.

Comment: i used:-encoding utf-8;-encodeing gb2312;-encoding gb18030;-encoding gbk and so on. but these option don't work yet

Comment: but i edit it in elipse with scala plugin ,and run it,well done!so i guess it's my scala compiler's problem about config of charset

Comment: the charset of the file in eclipse is gb18030